# Trying to reorder the sequence of which MySQL determines which entry is distinct by

Tags: mysql

Consider I have a Zoo Parent assigned to a Zoo Animal, I would like to get the ID's of all Zoo Parent which are distinct by the Zoo Animal's serial tag, What I'd want to do is:

```
SELECT
    zoo_parent.id
FROM
    zoo_parent
INNER JOIN
    zoo_animal ON (zoo_parent.animal_id = zoo_animal.id)
WHERE
    zoo_animal.is_active = "Y"
GROUP BY
    zoo_animal.serial_tag
```

The dilemma now is that I have a bunch of Zoo Animals with the same `serial_tag` because the owners of the software do not want to use historical records, instead they just save a new entry to the database using the same `serial_tag`. Their request to me is in a table that looks like this:

```
|------------------|------------------|-------------------|
|  Zoo Parent.id   |  Zoo Animal.id   | Zoo Animal.serial |
|------------------|------------------|-------------------|
|        1         |         1        |     ABC-100       |
|        2         |         2        |     ABC-200       |
|        3         |         3        |     ABC-300       |
|        4         |         4        |     ABC-100       |
|------------------|------------------|-------------------|
```

Ideally assuming running number for primary-key values, I would like to `GROUP BY zoo_animal.serial_tag` and get the `zoo_parent.id = 4` instead of zoo_parent.id = 1` (Latest "version" of this Parent's Animal's Serial Number). Note, they do not want me to change the schema in any way.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want the max id, use the MAX function:

```
SELECT
    MAX(zoo_parent.id) as max_id
FROM
    zoo_parent
INNER JOIN
    zoo_animal ON (zoo_parent.animal_id = zoo_animal.id)
WHERE
    zoo_animal.is_active = "Y"
GROUP BY
    zoo_animal.serial_tag
```